# Shared Memory Bank Conflicts in Parallel Reduction Algorithm

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, reduction, gpu-shared-memory

I was reading a slide-deck from Nvidia ([Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf)) discussing a parallel reduction algorithm.

Slide 15:
[image: slide about "sequential addressing" in a parallel reduction algorithm]

Here the writer discusses that by using sequential addressing, we avoid shared memory bank conflicts. I think this is wrong and here is my reason:

On slide 10 we assume that each thread block has 128 threads. In the sequential code provided in the blue box on the slide, thread 0 tries to use both `sdata[0]` and `sdata[64]` at the same and since we have 32 memory banks, these 2 accesses lead to a memory bank conflict.

Which part of my inference is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't about a bank conflicts between the read side `sdata[tid + s]` and the write side `sdata[tid]`. It is about the bank conflict **between neighboring threads within the same warp** for each operation (read or write) on its own. A warp can't do a read and a write operation in parallel in addition to the operations not being independent in this case. Operations that do not happen in parallel/lockstep can't cause bank conflicts.

Remember that threads within a warp (half-warp in very old GPUs) do their memory access in lockstep. In the first code, that index is strided by `2 * s`. So for example for `2 * s == 32`, each thread accesses the same bank, assuming 32 memory banks.

In the second code, all threads access array elements in sequential order without a stride and the index only differs by thread ID. So they always hit different memory banks.

### Edit

A quick warning: Note this from Nvidia's [Volta Tuning Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/volta-tuning-guide/index.html)

> Applications that assume reads and writes are implicitly visible to other threads in the same warp need to insert the new `__syncwarp()` warp-wide barrier synchronization instruction between steps where data is exchanged between threads via global or shared memory. Assumptions that code is executed in lockstep or that reads/writes from separate threads are visible across a warp without synchronization are invalid.

This affects the code in slide 22 (the unrolling of the last warp). Also, I'm pretty sure that part is better solved with [Warp Shuffle Functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) rather than using shared memory.

### Edit 2

The corresponding [CUDA sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/reduction/reduction_kernel.cu) on GitHub is updated appropriately. There is probably an updated version of the webinar somewhere, too.