# Grid-strided loop CUDA kernel: Pick optimal grid dimensions

Tags: c++, cuda

Let's say I have a large set of independent computations and instead of making one thread per work item, I want the CUDA threads to loop; maybe because the Z dimension is larger than CUDA's device limits or because it allows some reuse in parts of the computation. Let's say a kernel like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(dim3 size, float* arr, float div)
{
    int xoff = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int yoff = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int zoff = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    int xstride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int ystride = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;
    int zstride = blockDim.z * gridDim.z;
    for(int z = zoff; z < size.z; z += zstride)
        for(int y = yoff; y < size.y; y += ystride)
            for(int x = xoff; x < size.x; x += xstride)
                arr[(z * size.y + y) * size.x + x] /= div;
}
```

How do you set the grid dimensions for the kernel launch while avoiding issues with uneven work distribution? My current solution is this:

```cpp
void call(dim3 size, float* arr, float div)
{
    dim3 blocksize(16, 16);
    int blocksize1d = blocksize.x * blocksize.y * blocksize.z;
    int device, sm_count, sm_blocks;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);
    cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&sm_count, cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount, device);
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(
            &sm_blocks, kernel, blocksize1d, 0 /*shared memory*/);
    int active_blocks = sm_count * sm_blocks;
    dim3 blocks;
    blocks.x = min(active_blocks, (size.x + blocksize.x - 1) / blocksize.x);
    active_blocks /= blocks.x;
    blocks.y = min(active_blocks, (size.y + blocksize.y - 1) / blocksize.y);
    active_blocks /= blocks.y;
    blocks.z = min(active_blocks, (size.z + blocksize.z - 1) / blocksize.z);
    kernel<<<blocks, blocksize>>>(size, arr, div);
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better or canonical way for this style of kernel launch that I'm unaware of.

Comment: @talonmies Yes, I think that's exactly it

Comment: I usually start with a list of perfect squares and cubes and chose the largest less than `active_blocks`, but the relative dimensions of `size` should be considered somehow, especially if the input data is not close to equal size in all dimensions

Comment: @talonmies shouldn't the objective be to keep the iteration count per block equal? Or if not possible, that a small number of threads have one-less iteration, rather than a few threads having one more, as this would decrease occupancy?

Comment: On paper that’s correct, but I usually benchmarked a range of strategies and block sizes and build heuristics based on performance. Much of the time, aiming for maximum possible occupancy worked best, but not always

Comment: I wouldn't start with `dim3 blocksize(16, 16);`.  I would much prefer to start with `dim3 blocksize(32, 8);`

Comment: @RobertCrovella personally I prefer 16x16 since it makes transpositions through shared memory more natural and is still good for memory accesses as long as these are always done in half-warps. But sure, I'm happy to accept a solution in 32x8

Comment: Your "half-warp" statement is puzzling to me. I notice you stated it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490173/1695960) as well. Is there some NVIDIA documentation that says that memory accesses are always done in half-warps? I'm not sure what that means. A modern GPU memory controller should be able to coalesce across the request from a full warp.  And extending that idea, we can imagine at least pathological access patterns (not your example) that would generate twice as many transactions using a (16,16) block dimension vs. (32,8) block dimension, considered across the grid.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the heads-up. My understanding seems to be based on old recommendations, ca. 2.0 when, to my understanding, memory access was done (and coalesced) by half-warp. So transactions would naturally only matter for those, too. If you search the web you still find many mentions of that. I've now re-read the best practices guide and seen the sentence that with 6.0 you want as few 32 byte transactions per warp as possible